# How to End a Buttons ToolTip Display Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, button, tooltip

I have a button that launches a time intensive process. When the user hovers over this button a tool-tip is displayed, which is good. However, before this process gets re-routed onto a background thread (10 seconds or so for some stuff to take place) the tool-tip is displayed semi-transparent. I know this is awful coding and it should be put on to a non-UI thread ASAP, but this is the way it is for now...

My question is, how can I get a reference to the buttons tool-tip object so I can make it not visible? I envisage it to look like:

```
ToolTip someTT = Button.ToolTip; // This only gets or set the tool tip text.
someTT.Active = false;
someTT.Dispose(); // As a last resort.
```

Sorry guys, I aknowledge that I am a disgusting person for doing this.

**Edit:** The button is of the ComponantOne `RibbonButton`-type as part of the Studio for WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you working with the [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx), you can find the following code within the Form.InitializeComponent() method:

```
this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
//...
this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "Tooltip for button1");
```

Thus you can disable tooltip for the specific button using the same approach:

```
this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, null);
```

You can also disable a button when the background thread have been started. This also avoids unnecessary the tooltips above this button:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    toolTip1.Hide(button1);
    button1.Enabled = false;
    //start the background thread here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, due to the SDK I am using (ComponantOne) I cannot seem to find any reference to the generic ToolTip for the controls. If I could yours would be a very neat answer. I have set the tool-tips for the (ribbon)Buttons via the designer and it is not clear how to access the actual tool-tip object. Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should update your question with an information about ComponentOne controls you are using. Anyway setting the "null" value for the RibbonButton.Tooltip property or setting "false" value for RibbonButton.Enabled property should avoids tooltips showing (I do not know the actual C1's tooltip-engine architecture but I believe that it is not necessary to access the ToolTip-object directly in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with the [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) control that you added to your project. Something like [ToolTip.Active](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.active.aspx) might work.

From above link:

> With the Active property, you can enable or disable the display of
>   ToolTip text for all controls that have text specified by this
>   particular ToolTip component. Although more than one ToolTip component
>   can be created and assigned to a form, setting the Active property to
>   false only affects the current ToolTip.

Answer (score 0):

If the UI thread is doing work then it won't matter if you find a way to hide the tool tip, it still won't take place until the UI thread is freed up again.

Your solution is what you always knew it would be, move the non-UI processing to a non-UI thread.

Comment: This is not an answer to the above question.

Comment: @Killercam I assumed he was trying to hide the tool tip after the button was clicked, not in entirety before it is ever shown.  The fact that he says that the tooltip is good when hovering would seem to support that belief.  If we therefore assume that he's trying to hide the tooltip in the click event, and he is also doing 10 seconds worth of work in that click event, then any UI changes won't take place until they are too late.  The answer to his question is therefore that it can't be answered given his restraints.

Comment: You have it correct in what I wanted. It can be done. Just due to the fact that some processing is being done on the UI-thread does not mean I can't use that same thread to update/redraw some graphics etc. To illustrate I can trigger some hard work on the UI-thread -> 'do some hard work...' then midway through -> `myControl.Update()`, this will redraw `myControl`; at the expense of my processing ofcourse. Thanks for your time reguardless, it is appreciated...